# i want to show just my hotel's reservation LARAVEL 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

thats Reservation Table it have hotel_id

```
Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('hotel_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('hotel');
        $table->string('status')->default('pending');
        $table->integer('rooms');
        $table->date('checkin');
        $table->date('checkout');
        $table->timestamps();
```

i try getting just my hotels id and compare it with reservation hotel_id but not working

```
public function index()
{
    $myhotels = hotel::where('created_by',Auth::user()->id)->first('id');

 $reservations = Reservation::where('hotel_id',$myhotels)->get();

    return view('moderateur/reservation',compact('reservations'));
}
```

Comment: Try this ! 
$myhotels = hotel::where('created_by',Auth::user()->id)->first();
$reservations = Reservation::where('hotel_id',$myhotels->id)->get();

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `Hotel` instead of `hotel`. Case sensitive.

If you have relation between `1-n` between User and Hotel, and `1-n` between Hotel and Reservation it should be way easier.

```php
<?php

$reservation = User::with('hotels', 'hotels.reservations')->find(Auth::id());
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand you well , but try this

```
public function index()
{
    $myhotels = Hotel::where('created_by',Auth::user()->id)->pluck('id');

 $reservations = Reservation::where('hotel_id',$myhotels)->get();

    return view('moderateur/reservation',compact('reservations'));
}
```